Did English speakers always read "1789" aloud as "seventeen eighty-nine"? (Or was "seventeen hundred and eighty-nine"/other variants ever common?)
Today (almost) every English speaker would usually just read the year "1789" aloud as

"seventeen eighty-nine".

But we could also say

"seventeen hundred and eighty-nine"; or
"one thousand seven hundred and eighty-nine".

Was either 2 or 3 ever common (in spoken everyday English) and did English speakers transit to 1 at some time? (I know that in formal written English, 2 and 3 might sometimes have been used. But my question is about spoken everyday English.)
I believe Spanish, Italian, and French still use 3. There are also many other variants (e.g. the Chinese say "one seven eight nine", but I doubt this was ever common in English).
I ask because at least in 1966, William Buckley (1925–2008) quite consistently used 2 (though sometimes accidentally slipped into using the more common 1). This though could just be some pretentious affectation on his part. All of his interviewees consistently used 1 and I suspect so too did most people by 1966.

Related: Why do we say 'year 1993' as "nineteen ninety three" instead of "one thousand nine hundred ninety three"? and Is it improper English to read the number 1100 as "eleven hundred"?

It was quite common to spell out the year as a number in words, usually preceded by "the year of our lord".
Examples:

IT was profoundly observed by a witty member of the Court of Common Council, in Council assembled in the City of London, in the year of our Lord one thousand eight hundred and fifty, that the French are a frog-eating people, who wear wooden shoes.

Charles Dickens
A Monument of French Folly

It was in the year of our Lord one thousand seven hundred and forty-four, that I, Gill Davis to command, His Mark, having then the honour to be a private in the Royal Marines, stood a-leaning over the bulwarks of the armed sloop Christopher Columbus, in the South American waters off the Mosquito shore.

Charles Dickens
The Perils of Certain English Prisoners

TWAS on the 9th of September, a very beautiful day,
That a numerous English army came in grand array,
And pitched their tents on Flodden field so green
In the year of our Lord fifteen hundred and thirteen.

William McGonnagal
The Battle of Flodden Field
